# neo4j reference node obsolete but yet still returned from getAllNodes

Tags: neo4j

According to Neo4j [documentation](http://api.neo4j.org/1.9.4/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html) the "reference node concept is obsolete - indexes are the canonical way of getting hold of entry points in the graph.".

However if I use GlobalGraphOperations.getAllNodes() I'm still returned a node with id 0 which I didn't create and which has all the looks of a reference node.

I'm trying to implement a method getNode(String uuid)

```
   public Node getNode(String uuid)
    {
        GlobalGraphOperations globalGraphOperations = GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDb);
        for(Node tmpNode : globalGraphOperations.getAllNodes())
        {
            if(tmpNode.equals(graphDb.getReferenceNode()))
            { continue;}

            String tmpNodeUuid = (String)tmpNode.getProperty("uuid");
            if (tmpNodeUuid.equals(uuid))
            {
                return tmpNode;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

why does getAllNodes return a reference node? 
how to implement programmatically getNode() without using deprecated function getReferenceNode()?

Answer (score 0):

The reference node concept is indeed deprecated and will be removed with Neo4j version 2.0. In 1.x the concept still exists and the reference node is created when the database is intially created. If you don't need it, you can just delete the reference node. The method you're writing is gonna get slow as the graph grows as the entire graph is traversed. You should create an index for the UUID property and use that to look up nodes in the graph, which is much faster. As well as being the 'canonical way of getting hold of entry points in the graph' :-)